# In HMEventTrigger enable trigger shows error

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I am work with trigger on HomeKit, I face one error on enable trigger.
Error description :- **The operation couldn’t be completed. (HMErrorDomain error 12.)**. So please help me for figure out, i am using below code.

```
 var dateComponet = DateComponents()
    dateComponet.hour = 14
    dateComponet.minute = 25
    let calenderEvent = HMCalendarEvent(fire: dateComponet)
    let eventTriger = HMEventTrigger(name:"let's go for lunch", events: [calenderEvent], predicate: nil)
   eventTriger.enable(true) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        } else {
            print("Event add sucessfull")

        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't print `error.localizedDescription`, print `error`. Also, error 12 is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmerror/code/objectnotassociatedtoanyhome `HMError.Code.objectNotAssociatedToAnyHome`.

Comment: Thank you brother for nice suggestion but how can I resolve that in my code ? can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

So, before you call "enable" on the trigger, the trigger must be added to an instance of HMHome. Errorcode 12 says that your trigger isn't associated to any home object.

Once you add it with the "addTrigger" method on an HMHome (For example, HMHomeManager's .primaryHome), everything should work fine!

P.S.
Make sure to wait for the completion handler you pass to the addTrigger function. If you attempt to enable the trigger before that returns, HomeKit will still think it's unassociated.